# Lock All Column Changes, Except One Column On Trigger

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I want to ask how to lock all updates except one column with Trigger, is it possible to achieve this?

For example my table structure is:

```
--------------------------
id | name | age | point 
--------------------------
1  | Test | 10  | 10
2  | Test | 12  | 10
```

So what I want is to lock all changes update columns, except the point column.

Thank you in advance, sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to use permissions. If `datamoduser` is the database user that performs the data modifications, make sure the user has no permissions except

```
GRANT UPDATE (point) ON mytable TO datamoduser;
```

Then all `UPDATE` statements except the ones that update `point` will fail.